# unable to retrieve json data in objective-c

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm trying to retrieve json data from mysql database in iphone. [This is my .php file](http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php).

I would like to retrieve this data so that I have some code in my .m

```
- (void)jsonParse{
NSString* path  = @"http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

NSDictionary* resultDic = [dic objectForKey:@"maxid"];
NSString* recData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"recommendData"];
NSString* rData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"room"];
NSString* lData = [resultDic objectForKey:@"level"];

NSLog(@"recommendData = %@, room = %@, level = %@",recData,rData,lData);}
```

What I expect is to get data from recommendData, room, and level, but the debugger windows shows it did not get anything. This is what the debugger shows

```
2014-03-12 15:13:21.500 Semantic Museum[24289:907] recommendData = (null), room = (null), level = (null)
```

do I miss something??

Comment: Is `jsonString` non-nil? Is `jsonData` non-nil`? Is `dic` non-nil? is `resultDic` non-nil?

Comment: could be!! coz the codes seem all right. and the .php query can also produce json data. I don't know how to test it.

Comment: Put in these logs, NSLog(@"%@",jsonString),  NSLog(@"%@",jsonData),  NSLog(@"%@",dic) and report what they say.

Comment: it's odd!! it shows null ?? so that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks a problem with the server response headers.

I am seeing the `Content-Type` come back as

`text/html`

but it should be something like

`application/json`

Comment: how to check the server response headers?? where I can see text/html or application/json??

Comment: You can use a web proxy app like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or just `curl` the request in terminal with `-I `flag to grab the headers. Here is the full `curl` for this URL `curl -I http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php
`

Comment: Also to add: you should generally debug something like this by actually checking for possible errors returned by method calls. You are ignoring any possible errors for both`initWithContentsOfURL...` and `JSONObjectWithData`

Comment: You can also turn on verbosity in curl and it will show you the headers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming because it's static text(`try to View Source in your browser, it's returning extra parameter with JSON`). If it's JSON, you need to check that from PHP the header value is set properly.